# Error on map reduce example of Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop and after installing Hadoop 2.2.0 I tried to follow example  http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/45/run-hadoop-wordcount-mapreduce-example-windows to try a simple map reduce job.

However whenever I try to do the map reduce job over the txt file I created, I keep getting failures with this message

```
c:\hadoop>bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.ja
r wordcount /input output
14/03/26 14:20:48 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0
:8032
14/03/26 14:20:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Inste
ad, use mapreduce.job.user.name
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Inst
ead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is d
eprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is dep
recated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is depreca
ted. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated.
 Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is depr
ecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated
. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecate
d. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated
. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is dep
recated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecat
ed. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
14/03/26 14:20:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_13
95833928952_0004
14/03/26 14:20:52 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_13
95833928952_0004 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/03/26 14:20:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://GoncaloPe
reira:8088/proxy/application_1395833928952_0004/
14/03/26 14:20:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1395833928952_0004
14/03/26 14:21:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1395833928952_0004 running in uber
 mode : false
14/03/26 14:21:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/26 14:21:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395833928952_0004_m_000
000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileS
plit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
14/03/26 14:21:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395833928952_0004_m_000
000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileS
plit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
14/03/26 14:21:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395833928952_0004_m_000
000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileS
plit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
14/03/26 14:22:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/03/26 14:22:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1395833928952_0004 failed with sta
te FAILED due to: Task failed task_1395833928952_0004_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
14/03/26 14:22:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 6
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=48786
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
```

Since I followed everything with no issues step by step I have no idea why this might be, does anyone know?

Edit: Tried adopt 2.3.0 same issue happens with the example jar given, and the code bellow I tried compile, no idea what the issue is

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;


public class teste {

   public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
      private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();

      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         String line = value.toString();
         StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
         while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
         }
      }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
         throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         int sum = 0;
         for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
         }
         context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();

      Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

      job.setJarByClass(teste.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

      job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
      job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

      job.waitForCompletion(true);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue (`java.lang.ClassCastException`) and was able to solve it by running Hadoop with admin privileges. The problem seems to be the creation of symbolic links which by default is not possible for non-admin Windows users. Open a console as administrator and then proceed as described in the example from your link.

Comment: Thank you very much,I have been stuck for so long for such a silly thing.

Answer (score 0):

link you provided has input perameter as input NOT /input...try with this syntax...

```
C:\hadoop>bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount input output
```

if this doesn't work than see this - [Link](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/ST9IEjZtsj0)  and modify the mapper class.

Comment: I had forgotten to mention but I already had changed it into /input so that's not the issue. Also a bit of a shameful question but how do I modify the mapper?

Comment: use eclipse and See this tutorial...http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#running

Comment: Hmm I was sure 2.2.0 had no eclipse plugin

Comment: Nope I went to check and it's using the correct API, so it can't be that.

Comment: hi...what does these two commands returns? 1--> bin\hdfs dfs -ls input/ and 2--> bin\hdfs dfs -cat input/file1.txt

Comment: First one shows me the folder files and the 2nd one prints what is written in my file1.txt . So everything is ok on that end.